# if 3 SAT is reduced to A, as well as A is reduced to 3SAT, then is A in NPC?

Tags: np-complete

if 3 SAT is reduced to A, as well as A is reduced to 3SAT, then is A in NPC ?

If yes then how can we generate a polynomial time verifier algorithm for the same ?

Answer (score 4):

A polynomial from $3SAT$ to $A$ shows that $A$ is $NP$-hard.

A polynomial reduction from $A$ to $3SAT$ shows that $A$ is in $NP$.

So, the answer is yes.

You can construct a polynomial verification algorithm for $A$ by first reducing $A$ to $3SAT$, and then using the verification algorithm for $3SAT$.

Comment: Is it true only for 3SAT or all NPC problems in general? I mean were these reductions be true for all NPC problems.                                   Reducing the problem to 3SAT assures that I can somehow use 3SAT's solution to solve the problem, but does it also guarantee that its verification algorithm can be used to verify my problem A. So as a conclusion if i can reduce a problem to some specific problem say X, then can I also use X's verification algorithm to verify my problem ?

Comment: @TarGate: yes, it comes from the fact that a reduction $f$ from $A$ to $X$ is so that $x\in A\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in X$. Thus, an algorithm (be it deterministic or not) that decides if $f(x)$ is in $X$ also decides if $x$ is in $A$.